Why do photons obey Bose-Einstein statistics?
In a typical derivation of Bose-Einstein distribution using Lagrange multipliers, the total number of particles is assumed to be fixed. But for photons, the total number is not fixed, say in blackbody radiation experiment. Why does photons obey Bose-Einstein statistics nonetheless?

They are bosons, are they not?

@controlgroup Yes, they are. Are you saying that bosons should follow Bose-Einstein distribution because there is  "Bose" in the name?

From the Wikipedia page: "Bose–Einstein statistics apply only to particles that do not follow the Pauli exclusion principle restrictions. Particles that follow Bose-Einstein statistics are called bosons, which have integer values of spin. In contrast, particles that follow Fermi-Dirac statistics are called fermions and have half-integer spins." Fermions follow Fermi-Dirac statistics and bosons follow Bose-Einstein statistics - hence the names "boson" and "fermion".

@controlgroup My argument is this: The Lagrange multiplier derivation of BE statistics assumes that the total number of particles is fixed. For photons, the total number is not fixed. Therefore, there is no reason why photons should obey BE statistics.

There has been a Nature paper around 2010, which describes the generation of an optical BEC (in a cavity???). As far as I remember, they discussed your question. Might be worth looking it up.

Technically, the BE statistics only rigorously apply in the grand canonical ensemble where you fix the chemical potential and not the number of particles. This is why it is exact for photons and in particular for blackbody radiation for which $\mu=0$. For a finite number of bosons $N$, it only applies in the thermodynamic limit $N\to\infty$. Your question should therefore be rather the opposite, why does it apply say to cold atoms, rather than photons.

I don't see anything not rigorous in the Lagrange multiplier method of derivation, though...
